# ¿Cómo podría cambiar mi página principal XTHML a otra XHTML la cual pertenece un login?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, maven, wildfly

soy un programador nuevo y quisiera que me pudiesen dar una mano con este pequeño problema, primero antes que todo se usa Primefaces 6.0 y maven 3.6.3. Mi consulta es quisiera cambiar la página de inicio de mi aplicación, directamente a un login. Lo que he hecho hasta momento es a mi index.xhtml le pase todo lo contenido en loginAdmin.xhtml, pero sin embargo no se muestra el form de inicio de sesión. Qué me recomendarían hacer? .Qué me recomendarían hacer en está situación, qué opciones tendría, volver a el estado anterior el index.xhtml a un html normal y de qué manera apuntaría a loginAdmin.
[image: Se ve de esta manera]

[image: Y me gustaría que se vea de esta manera]

Alguna idea de como poder hacer que redireccione a esa página xhtml? O directamente al abrir la aplicación salga el loginAdmin?
 Acá les pongo ambos códigos:

loginAdmin.xhtml y index.xhtml(Son iguales los modifique para que se vean exactamente iguales):

````
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:b="http://bootsfaces.net/ui"
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:tnt="http://java.sun.com/jsf/composite/components"
       xmlns:o="http://omnifaces.org/ui" 
     > 
<h:head>

  <h:outputStylesheet  name="style.css" library="css"></h:outputStylesheet>
  <link href="/primax.png" rel="shortcut icon" />
  <link rel="shortcut icon" href="landing/img/favicon.ico" />
<title>Bienvenido a PRIMAX</title>

<style type="text/css">

html, body {
  height: 100%;
    background-image: url('resources/images/background_image.png');
    /*background-color: #f5f5f5;*/
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;

}


.jumbotron.vertical-center {
  margin-bottom: 0; /* Remove the default bottom margin of .jumbotron */
}

.vertical-center {
  min-height: 100%;  /* Fallback for vh unit */
  min-height: 100vh; 
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -moz-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: flex; 


    -webkit-box-align : center;
  -webkit-align-items : center;
       -moz-box-align : center;
       -ms-flex-align : center;
          align-items : center;

  width: 100%;

      -webkit-box-pack : center;
            -moz-box-pack : center;
            -ms-flex-pack : center;
  -webkit-justify-content : center;
          justify-content : center;
}

</style>


<script type= "text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[


function handleRequestLogin(xhr, status, args) {  

if(args.validationFailed || args.notValid || args.ok==false) {  
     PF('btnIngresar').enable();
} else {  


}  
} 
//]]>
</script>

</h:head>
<h:body>
<f:view>
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<div class="jumbotron vertical-center"> 
<b:form horizontal="true">
<b:container style="max-width:400px">
<div class="">
<p:growl id="msjLogin" showDetail="true">
</p:growl>
    <b:panel title="Iniciar Sesión" collapsible="false">
        <span style="width:100%;display:block;text-align:center;padding-bottom:40px;">
            <h:graphicImage url="resources/images/logoPrimaxGO.png" width="247" height="43"  />
        </span>
        <b:inputText placeholder="Usuario" value="#{loginMB.userName}" required="true"  id="txtUser" requiredMessage="Ingrese su usuario" colMd="12" >
            <f:facet name="prepend">
              <b:icon name="user" />
            </f:facet>
          </b:inputText>

          <b:inputSecret placeholder="Contraseña"  value="#{loginMB.password}" required="true"  id="pwd" requiredMessage="Ingrese su contraseña" colMd="12" >
            <f:facet name="prepend">
              <b:iconAwesome name="key" />
            </f:facet>
          </b:inputSecret>
          <p:commandButton widgetVar="btnIngresar" styleClass="btn btn-primax" style="width:335px;height:46px;margin-top:10px; border-color: #f0ad4e; background: #f0ad4e none repeat scroll 0 0;color: #ffffff;" colMd="12"   value="Ingresar" action="#{loginMB.autenticarAdmin}" validateClient="true" partialSubmit="true" update="txtUser,pwd,msjLogin"  onstart="PF('btnIngresar').disable();"  oncomplete="handleRequestLogin(xhr, status, args);" />
    </b:panel>


<!-- <span class="login-link-container" >
<p:commandLink value="¿Olvidaste tu Contraseña?" styleClass="login-link"  immediate="true" global="false"/>
</span> -->

<span style="display:block;width:100%;text-align:center;margin:5px">
<p:ajaxStatus style="width:100%">  
    <f:facet name="start">  
        <p:graphicImage value="#{resource['images:ajax-loader-bar.gif']}" />  <h:outputText value=" Validando credenciales" /> 
         </f:facet>  

    <f:facet name="complete">  
        <h:outputText value=" " />  
    </f:facet>  
</p:ajaxStatus>
</span>
</div>

</b:container>

</b:form>
<span id="copyright">
    <strong>2016 - 2020 © PRIMAX. </strong> Todos los derechos reservados.
</span>
 </div>
 </f:view>
</h:body>
</html> ```

Qué me recomendarían hacer en está situación, qué opciones tendría, volver a el estado anterior el index.xhtml a un html normal y de qué manera apuntaría a loginAdmin.
[![Se ve de esta manera][1]][1]


[![Y me gustaría que se vea de esta manera][2]][2]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aGvdm.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/p0ngu.png

Alguna idea de como poder hacer que redireccione a esa página xhtml? O directamente al abrir la aplicación salga el loginAdmin?
````

Answer (score 1):

Conseguí resolverlo, en web.xml ,

> tuve que modificar el "welcome-file", apuntando a loginAdmin.xthml

Comment: Si esta es la solución a tu problema por favor no olvides marcarla como aceptada

Answer (score 0):

También puede solucionarse colocando lo siguiente en el index.jsp

```
<%
  response.sendRedirect("paginas/estaEsMiPaginaPrincipal.jsf");
%>
```

o

```
<%
    String redirectURL = "http://proyecto/miJSP.jsp";
    response.sendRedirect(redirectURL);
%>
```